# Multidimensional Tensor slicing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras-layer, tensorflow2.0

First things first: I'm relatively new to TensorFlow.

I'm trying to implement a custom layer in tensorflow.keras and I'm having relatively hard time when I try to achieve the following:

1. I've got 3 Tensors `(x,y,z)`  of shape `(?,49,3,3,32)` [where ? is the batch size]
2. On each Tensor I compute the sum over the 3rd and 4th axes [thus I end up with 3 Tensors of shape `(?,49,32)`]
3. By doing an argmax `(A)`on the above 3 Tensors `(?,49,32)` I get a single `(?,49,32)` Tensor

Now I want to use this tensor to select slices from the initial `x,y,z` Tensors in the following form:

- Each element in the last dimension of `A` corresponds to the selected Tensor.
  (aka: `0 = X, 1 = Y, 2 = Z`)
- The index of the last dimension of `A` corresponds to the slice that I would like to extract from the Tensor last dimension.

I've tried to achieve the above using `tf.gather` but I had no luck. Then I tried using a series of `tf.map_fn`, which is ugly and computationally costly.

To simplify the above: 
let's say we've got an A array of shape (3,3,3,32). Then the numpy equivalent of what I try to achieve is this:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(3,3,32)
y = np.random.rand(3,3,32)
z = np.random.rand(3,3,32)
x_sums = np.sum(np.sum(x,axis=0),0);
y_sums = np.sum(np.sum(y,axis=0),0);
z_sums = np.sum(np.sum(z,axis=0),0);
max_sums = np.argmax([x_sums,y_sums,z_sums],0)
A = np.array([x,y,z])
tmp = []
for i in range(0,len(max_sums)):
    tmp.append(A[max_sums[i],:,:,i) 
output = np.transpose(np.stack(tmp))
```

Any suggestions? 
ps: I tried `tf.gather_nd` but I had no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do something like that with [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd):

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Make example data
tf.random.set_seed(0)
b = 10  # Batch size
x = tf.random.uniform((b, 49, 3, 3, 32))
y = tf.random.uniform((b, 49, 3, 3, 32))
z = tf.random.uniform((b, 49, 3, 3, 32))
# Stack tensors together
data = tf.stack([x, y, z], axis=2)
# Put reduction axes last
data_t = tf.transpose(data, (0, 1, 5, 2, 3, 4))
# Reduce
s = tf.reduce_sum(data_t, axis=(4, 5))
# Find largest sums
idx = tf.argmax(s, 3)
# Make gather indices
data_shape = tf.shape(data_t, idx.dtype)
bb, ii, jj = tf.meshgrid(*(tf.range(data_shape[i]) for i in range(3)), indexing='ij')
# Gather result
output_t = tf.gather_nd(data_t, tf.stack([bb, ii, jj, idx], axis=-1))
# Reorder axes
output = tf.transpose(output_t, (0, 1, 3, 4, 2))
print(output.shape)
# TensorShape([10, 49, 3, 3, 32])
```